# Toast Message in ios with multiline

Tags: ios, toast, mbprogresshud

I Am looking for a Toast Message Library such as `MBProgressHUD`, which contains loading screen with message and without, detail text and only text message.

But `MBProgressHUD` not have the support for multiline toast message only in showing text message

Can anyone suggest me a Library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Please use `detailsLabelText` property of `MBProgressHUD`. It supports multiline text.

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
hud.detailsLabelText = @"Your multiline text here ......."                           
hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
hud.margin = 10.f; 
[hud hide:YES afterDelay:2];
```

Answer (score 2):

This library does what you need [DCToastView](https://github.com/vberihuete/DCToastView) allowing you to provide toast messages from the top or bottom side of the screen using auto layout and stackviews it **renders as many lines as you need**:

[image: DCToastViewSample]

You will just need to add the pod

`pod 'DCToastView'`

Import it where you want to use it.

`import DCToastView`

And use it

`ToastPresenter.shared.show(in: self.view, message: "This is a toast")`

You can pass the following properties to the show method:

- **view**: The view in which the toast is going to be presented
- **message**: The message that the toast will show
- **toastPlace**: The place which can be .down or .up
- **backgroundColor**: The background color of the toast; defaults to black
- **textColor**: The text color of the message; defaults to white
- **timeOut**: The amount of seconds for the toast to dismiss if not provided it means that the toast will be sticky (will remain until touched); defaults to nil
- **roundness**: How round the toast will be: .none, .low, .mid, .high; defaults to .mid

Answer (score 1):

**This is something, which was needed by you. Created with lot of Animation Options, screen positions, and duration. Even you can provide your own duration. Check that out below.**

[AVIToast Link](https://github.com/avistyles/AVIToast)

ToastThis Supports Multiline toasts.

Comment: The link to given library seems not to work. Could you please fix it?

Comment: It is fixed now, Thanks for Informing. Please up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to display multiline messages with MBProgressHUD using this code:

```
MBProgressHUD *h = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

h.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
h.labelText = n.userInfo[@"message"];
h.labelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];

[h hide:YES afterDelay:1];
```